# AS3 remove FreeTransformManager move Easing

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm using the FTS of Ryan Tan, by default it got an easing when you move the object, i searched in the code but i couldn't find how to remove it!

This is my set up

```
var fts:FreeTransformManager = new FreeTransformManager(false);

fts.dragArea = new Rectangle(0,0,3400,1000);
fts.boundingBoxOutlineThickness = 10;
fts.handleRadius = 0;
fts.handleOutlineThickness = 0;
fts._boundingBoxOutlineColor = 0xff9933;
fts.handleFillColor = 0x33cc33;
fts.buttonMode = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I Solved it by changing all `Stage.mouseX` by `me.mouseX` in the freeTransformManager.as